# Error creating address locator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geocoding

I keep receiving a build error when i'm creating an address locator. The file i'm using to create the locator has 4 fields to indicate starting and ending addresses on either side of the street. As such, i've tried using the "US Address - Dual Ranges" address locator style with the following settings:

[image]

The fields L_LADD & L_HADD indicate the start and end of the "left" side of house numbers along a segment while the R_LADD & R_HADD identify the start and end of the "right" side. I've included some sample values from each field below.

[image]

Running this gives me the following error:

[image]

I'm not sure why i'm getting this error or how to fix it.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: Sorry about that.